# Friends Chandler "For Flanin"

Tags: dialogue, friends

In *Friends* S1E24,

> Chandler slips and lets everyone know Ross loves Rachel

As he vainly tries to cover it up, he says "for...flanin". What is the meaning of this? I can't find anything and I haven't ever seen such a word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what he had said earlier,

> ... Remember back in college, when he ***fell in love*** with Carol and bought her that ridiculously expensive crystal duck?

Later when Rachel questioned him,Chandler said:

> [stuttering incoherently] ***F-hah***.... ***flennin***....

He actually jumbled up the letters of **fell in love** and created a meaningless word "**flennin**".